# How to change UIButton title text dynamically

Tags: ios, uibutton

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self addMyButton];   // Call add button method on view load
}

- (void)addMyButton {     // Method for creating button, with background image and other properties    
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"Show More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 500.0, 160.0, 40.0);    
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)aMethod {
    NSLog(@"in load more n===>>>%d",n);
    [tbl reloadData];    
}
```

There is an `NSMutableArray` containing thirty objects. First only ten objects should be shown, and after clicking on the 'show more' button twenty objects will show, and after clicking a second time on the button then thirty objects should be shown and the button title will become 'Return'. When I click on 'Return' then the table view should only show twenty objects again. After the next click ten elements should be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is dynamically attached, you must create a reference to it.

You can use a counter, like this:

```
-(void) aMethod{

    if(ctr < arrayLength){
          ctr++;
          [buttonReference setText:@"Show More"];
    } else {
          ctr--;
          [buttonReference setText:@"Return"];
    }
     .....
}
```

Comment: Here button is work properly but how will Return button work?.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void) aMethod{
if(n==2)
{
    [button setTitle:@"Return" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
  //  n--;
}
else
{        [button setTitle:@"Show More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
NSLog(@"n==>>  %d",n);
[tbl reloadData];}

Here is my code.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this work by three ways

1: Declare your button in private interface  in implementation file, so that you can access the button anywhere in the class.

2: Declare aMethod() with the (id)sender parameter and access type the sender to UIButton.

3: Add the tag property of UIButton in AddMyButton `button.tag = 1;` and reference the button in aMethod

```
-(void)aMethod
{
    UIButton *button2 = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
    [button2 setTitle:@"return" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSLog(@"in load more n===>>>");
    [tbl reloadData];
}
```